# Encrypt and decrypt the dataset

Tags: encryption, rijndael

I'm loading the data into dataset form SQL Server. Now I wanna this data to be write in XML file in encrypted form and save it somewhere in disk.

On reading this XML into dataset, I wanna dataset to be encrypt again.

I have used "**RijndaelSimple** class to encrypt and decrypt dataset, but it takes much time to complete execution as it do it row by row in dataset.  I have around 50000 rows in dataset.

Is there any other option I have to encrypt and decrypt dataset on a go?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you really need that rigorous of an encryption scheme, or do you just need to hide the data from the user casually?

Comment: I have some sensitive info in xml file. so i just need to save it to my disk in decrypeted form. On reading this xml using ds.ReadXml(), i wanna this dataset to be encypt again. i am using c#

Comment: OK, so you're currently using [`RijndaelManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) class?  I don't see a `RijndaelSimple` class in the MSDN documentation.